# Ambiguity in close vote numbers

Tags: support, vote-to-close

When I cast a vote to close a Q, it says

> 24 votes remaining

But in reality the Q gets closed in 5 votes.

Can anyone please explain this ambiguity?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [help center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions),

> - It takes 5 close votes to reach the closing threshold (except for duplicate questions, which can be marked as duplicate with a single vote from a user who has earned a gold tag badge in one of that question's current tags, unless that user participated in editing the tags).
> - You may cast up to 24 close votes per day.

It means a user has a limit of 24 votes per day which they can use for closing a question.

**But in reality the Q gets closed in 5 votes.**

These 5 votes are voted by five different users/reviewers.

Comment: It seems u r correct..The link https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions was confusing where the image says "24 votes remaining" but description says "You may cast up to 50 close votes per day"; "It takes 5 close votes to reach the closing threshold"...

Comment: @YDS I don't know about SO and [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/close-questions) also says 50. I think they have different number or maybe a bug.

Comment: There is no bug. For sites with small review queues, the limit is 24 and for large, it is 50 close votes. For review tasks, the limit is 20 for small sites and 40 if the queue is large.